# Type '{ }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & {}'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm doing the PluralSight intro course on React, and one of the projects in the course involves building a web UI that allows the user to enter a GitHub username, and the app will add the corresponding GitHub profile photo to a list of profiles on the app.

The courses writes everything in standard js, but I am trying to use TypeScript because its what my company uses. I am running into an issue where I want to pass a setState (hook) function reference as a prop to a child component.

Here is the code in the parent component:

```
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = React.useState<GitHubData[]>([]);     // **** HOOK HERE

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.title}>The Github Cards App</Typography>
      <Divider />
      <Form onSubmit={setProfiles} />          // **** ISSUE IS HERE ****
      <CardList profiles={profiles} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using a bunch of material-UI stuff, but the important piece is the `<Form onSubmit={setProfiles} />`, which is the function reference that is giving me the error (specified in title).

For more context, here are the relevant interfaces and component definitions:

```
interface GitHubData {
  name: string,
  avatar_url: string,
  company: string,
  location?: string
}

interface updaterFunction {
  updateProfiles: Dispatch<SetStateAction<GitHubData>>       // From suggestions online
  updateProfiles: (newProfile: GitHubData) => void           // (What I hoped would work)
}

const Form = (props: updaterFunction) => { ... }
```

The full error is as follows:

```
Type '{ onSubmit: Dispatch<SetStateAction<GitHubData[]>>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & updaterFunction'.

Property 'onSubmit' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & updaterFunction'
```

What can I do to get rid of it? I've seen a bunch of similar errors online, but none of the proposed solutions have worked for me. Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that your interface should use the `onSubmit` key instead of `updateProfiles`:

```
interface updaterFunction {
  onSubmit: ...  // try with the options you mentioned
}
```

That's what the second line seems to indicate in your error message.

By the way, it would make sense to rename your interface to something like `FormProps` here.

Comment: I changed it to onSubmit (and FormProps, thanks for the tip), but I also had to update the parameter type specifier- `onSubmit: (profiles: GitHubData[]) => void` . The hook setter takes the entire new array, not just the single new GitHubData object that is getting appended.

Comment: **Correction pt 2:** the ultimate solution involved not passing the state hook (`setProfiles`) to the child component, but rather a reference to a wrapper function that calls `setProfiles` (`addNewProfile`, which I wrote in my App component, and passed to my Form component). I had this function take a single `GitHubData` object, so I reverted the change mentioned in my previous comment (above). It simply concat's the new profile passed as the argument to the profiles state array.